# Possible argument against Height bound hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

From [this paper](http://www6.cityu.edu.hk/ma/doc/people/smales/pap104.ps).

$f(x,y)$ is polynomial with integer coefficients.

$s(f)$ is its size, the sum of the logarithms of the absolute
values of the nonzero coefficients, defined on p. 6. From p. 7.

> **Height bound hypothesis**: If the curve $f$, of positive genus, has any integer
> solution, then it has a solution $(a, b)$ satisfying the estimate; $\log \max(|a|, |b|)$ is polynomially bounded by $s(f)$.

For integer $n>2$, let $f_n$ be the curve $y^2=x^{2n}+x-3$.

For all $n$, $s(f_n)=\log{3}$ and $(3,3^n),(3,-3^n)$ are on $f_n$.

In both cases $\log \max(|a|, |b|)=n \log 3$ which is not polynomial
in $\log{3}$ since $n$ is unbounded.

So for all $n$, the hypothesis implies at least one more point
polynomial in $\log{3}$.

I don't think this is possible, since $y \sim x^n$ which implies either $|x|=1$ or $y=0$ and these are not the curve (the second is on $y^2=x^{2n}+x-2$).

> Q1 For all $n$, is there third integral point satisfying the hypothesis?
>
> Q2 Assuming third integral point doesn't exists, does this contradict the hypothesis?

Searching for points with `ratpoints` doesn't show more integral points.

Comment: The hypothesis does not of course hold as stated. I am assuming Smale meant it implicit that the degree of $f$, or at least the geometric genus of the curve, is fixed.
But then, if that is the case, a much stronger hypothesis placing a bound $\log\max(|a|,|b|) \ll_{\deg{f}} s(f)$ on all solutions, is apparently a common belief. Cf. the "effective Mordell" problem.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov You might be right, but don't see this on paper, might be wrong. Lagarias comments genus 1 on pp 7,8 here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611209